# How implement row-level authorization at the data access level in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

I want to restrict the access to the rows of one or more entities based on the rights or the role of the current user.

For example :
I want to ensure that users can only access those data rows that i have specified in Admin Panel, or I want to restrict a users to see only the data Reports that  that i have specified in Admin Panel.

I have a tree that display all of the report names, I want to filter this tree based on role of the current user.

Comment: _Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._ Please ask a more specific question, i.e. when you have an issue about a concrete implementation. And also provide your previous efforts you have done to solve it. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), especially sections 1-3

Comment: Do you want to filter the tree or do you want to show a given user just the reports you specified (for the given user) in your admin panel?

Comment: I want to show a given user just the reports I specified (for the given user) in my admin panel.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you reading this from a database?